# Call external batch in WinSCP to capture console output

Tags: scripting, console, winscp

I have a WinSCP code written for some file transfer ... That's working fine.

My requirement is: before I exit from WinSCP console, I want to execute another batch to take a screenshot of that WinSCP console and then I want to say `bye` to the WinSCP console. But as long as the second operation is not complete, I don't want to exit the WinSCP console.

I tried:

```
winscp> Call %some_path%\test.bat
```

but it says some error like:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `call` command executes the command on the server.

You cannot execute local commands from WinSCP script.

But you can execute WinSCP from a batch file and take a screenshot from the batch after WinSCP finishes. Make sure that you execute the [`winscp.com` (not the `winscp.exe`)](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/executables). The `winscp.com` is a console application. It inherits the console of the parent batch, so you do not loose WinSCP output after it finishes.

```
winscp.com /script.txt
%some_path%\test.bat
```

Anyway, I do not really understand the purpose of this. Wouldn't it be better, if you redirect the output of the `winscp.com` to a log file?

```
winscp.com /script=script.txt > output.txt
```

Or maybe even better, use a log file (the [`/log=<path>` command line parameter](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/commandline#logging)). The log includes whole output of the WinSCP console, and lot more.

Comment: Thank you very much Martin !
Yes you were right my requirement is little weird .
But I can use the log file too for the same .I will get back to you in case of any problem .